Help me find what robot show this is
I need help finding out what this animated show is. It is about this guy who finds a tiny robot. The robot goes on to his chest and he turns into a suit.  It is a blue silver-ish suit and robot.

Did you see it on TV? YouTube? A DVD? Was the guy Asian? Caucasian? Black? Alien?

Like saw it on like Netflix or Hulu and he was white and the robot was like an alien thing

In roughly which year did you watch this and was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?

Maybe Guyver? There's been a few animated versions.

Max Steel
There is a Live action Movie and several animated iterations
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Steel_(disambiguation)



